# unit test in boost

Tags: c++, boost

I have the following code for my unit test:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE (test_adapter) {
  boost::random::mt19937 gen;
  boost::normal_distribution<> nd1(10.0,31.0);
  unsigned int imax = 1000;
  std::vector<double> x, x_p;
  for (unsigned int k = 0 ; k < 1000 ; k++) {
    std::vector<double>().swap(x);
    std::vector<double>().swap(x_p);
    for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < imax ; i++) {
      x.push_back(nd1(gen));
      x_p.push_back(nd1(gen));
        }
   }
        log_rtns <double >lr;
        BOOST_CHECK(lr( x, x_p) == false );
```

}

and this is my log_rtns:

```
template<class T>
class log_rtns: public std::binary_function<T,T,bool> {
 public:
  inline bool operator()(T t, T t_p) {return (std::log(t/t_p));}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a `log_rtns` variable (here `log_rtns lr;`) without specifying the template parameter `T`. So you have to write `log_rtns<something> lr;`.

I would guess you want `log_rtns<double>`, but the `lr` variable is not used.

Also you can't call `BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE()` on two arrays. You have to do something like

```
BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(x.size(), x_p.size());
for (size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i) {
    BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE(x[i], x_p[i], 0.00000000000);
}
```

Comment: You can't use zero tolerance either. You need to specify which percent difference between values is acceptable. If you rather want to check for equality you can use BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL_COLLECTIONS

Comment: @Florian Sowade, thanks for the example, I think I need to redo my code :-(